# Probability. About round table

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Mr. A, Mr. B and 6 more people wants to sit around round table. We need to find out the probability that Mr. A and Mr. B will sit near each other. First of all we need to describe $(\Omega,F,P)$

I think $n= (8-7)!=5040$ than Mr. A and Mr. B we can keep as one because we want them to sit near each other. Tham $m=(7-1)!*2=1440$ Than $P=m/n=1440/5040=2/7$ Is ir right?

And how I should describe $(\Omega,F,P)$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: As herb steinberg mentioned in his "answer", this question post seems like a duplicate. Does anyone have a good candidate that other similar posts have been closed as a duplicate to?

Answer (score 1):

(Looks like a duplicate).  Simple way to get 2/7.  Seat A any place.  There are 2 out of 7 places for B to sit next to A.